# custom Listview Row textview Text push the Imageview on Right

Tags: android, image, listview, textview, row

i am trying to make a simple listview with

image_Left + textview_center + image_Right  But I encountered a problem (see the picture ) [image]

textview pushing image_Right any solutions for resolve this isseu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffff"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#ffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/info"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/solutionText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:textColor="#383838"
    android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/more"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout: use `android:layout_weight` attribute and `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/solutionText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAHBLAHBLAH BLAH"
        android:textColor="#383838"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes in your code itself, try replacing your code with this which uses the concept of `layout_weight` and `weightSum` attributes. Read [this](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/layout-weights-part-1/) for info about weights. Good luck

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffff"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/info"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/solutionText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:textColor="#383838"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/more"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

</LinearLayout>
```